# How to wrap a text around an image using CSS

Tags: html, css

Below is my code. I wished to wrap my text around the image. I used `q {float: left; width: 100%}`. However, the text appeared below the image.

```
<p class = "review">
  <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
  <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
</p>
```

Is there any other way to wrap my text around the image? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p class = "review">
<img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" style="float:left"/>
<q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
</p>
```

Comment: This would be better without inline styles!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<q>` display property to `display:inline` and remove the `width` property. That will align it next to the image

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to float the image left. That will cause the behavior you want - having the text wrap around the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use span tages or use `display:inline` in your css:

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/hbtn9853/1/)

```
<span>Hello!</span><span><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" /></span><span>How are you!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to float the `image` not `q`

```css
.review {width:100%;}
.review img {float:left; margin:7px; vertical-align:top;}
```

```html
<p class = "review">
<img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
<q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
  <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
  <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
</p>
```